# What are the power requirements of the SNES Classic?

Tags: snes-classic

The description I see on most online retailers for Nintendo’s bundle of nostalgia includes something like:

> Note that an AC adapter for the USB cable is required to play the system but is not included in the packaging.

Now, there’s an “official” one for around a quarter of the price of the console, but is this necessary?

Would a phone charger plug work? A bog standard powered USB hub? The USB port on my television?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned on [arstechnica](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2017/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-super-nes-classic-edition/)

> Even though the Super NES Classic Edition is rated for five watts, it
>   only draws 2.3W from the provided USB adapter. The USB Micro power
>   cord can be plugged in to any sufficiently powerful source, including
>   a laptop or the USB power outputs on many modern TVs.

This basically means that you do not need to buy the official charger and most, if not any charger would work.